# Average distance between two randomly chosen indexes in array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, probability

Interesting thought question for you guys. Given an array of length *n*, if I were to pick two random indexes in this array, *a* and *b* on average how far apart would they be? As in how many steps would I have to take to walk from *a* to *b*. There are no restrictions so there's a chance I pick the same index for both, and there's a chance *a* and *b* are at opposite ends of the array.

I've thought about this for a while, my initial idea being they're on average n/2(ish) apart, but I think this hunch is incorrect. An index chosen in the center of the array *at most* would have to walk n/2 places to find its corresponding second choice, whereas only at the ends of the array would the second choice ever be around n distance away.

Thanks!

Comment: True but I'm curious if there's a way to prove or explain this probability (apparently it's n/3 in practice)

Comment: Isn't this a maths question smuggled onto Stackoverflow by framing it in terms of an array?

Comment: 1) are math and algorithms questions that different? 2) this is an algorithms homework problem 3) stack overflow has an algorithms tag so I used it.

Comment: @stovroz If the question were about continuous intervals of real numbers, it would clearly be for http://math.stackexchange.com/.  But since it is a discrete array, I think it could go either way.

Comment: I could see this as being closed for being off topic.  But I don't understand "unclear what you're asking".  There's four answers that interpret the question the exact same way.  And I can prove that @stovroz 's answer is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After scribbling some grids of possible distances for the first few values of n, I think the exact result is in fact given by:

```
f(n) = (n² - 1) / 3n
```

Comment: +1 This is the only answer that matches what I'm seeing. In addition, the probability of any *specific* interval `k` is `2(n-k) / n^2`.

Comment: This answer is correct.  I'd post a rigorous derivation of it if the question hadn't been placed on-hold.

Answer (score 2):

Choosing two places in an array is equivalent to splitting the array up into 3 sections. The average size of each of those sections will be n/3 so the average distance between the two points is also n/3.

Comment: This sounds very reasonable to me.

Comment: Or rather it tends to n/3.

Comment: Agreed, this only works over large n (like take n == 4 it doesn't work). But I think it's elegant and solves it for me.

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret No, it's not evenly distributed. For example, there are `n` ways to get a distance of 0, while there are only ever 2 ways to get a distance of `n-1`

Comment: You're absolutely right. I should think, then speak. :) Edit: dumb comment removed, I don't want to confuse people, since it was dead wrong.

Comment: To get an exact distance of `n/3`, the odds *should* be `4/3n`, unless my math skills have eroded.

Answer (score 1):

Using a monte carlo method in python:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import random

sample = [abs(random.choice(range(0,10)) - random.choice(range(0,10))) for i in range(0,10000)]

avg = float(sum(sample) / len(sample))
print ("Average: %f" % avg)

freq = defaultdict(int)
for s in sample:
    freq[s] += 1

scale = 40.0 / max(freq.values())
for i in range(0,10):
    print ("%d : %s" % (i, "#" * int(freq[i] * scale)))
```

Output:

```
Average: 3.293700
0 : ######################
1 : ########################################
2 : ####################################
3 : ###############################
4 : ##########################
5 : ######################
6 : #################
7 : #############
8 : #########
9 : ####
```

So, looks like it's `n/3` - but it's not evenly distributed.

Comment: Does my answer below make sense? Twas inspired by your research.

Comment: It would be very interesting to try this again without taking the absolute value of the difference, giving a range of (-n,n) (exclusive). I think you'll get something closer to a gaussian distribution.

Comment: @beaker It's not Gaussian, it's triangular.  Think of it as an n by n matrix where the row's are the index of the first number and the columns are the index of the second. Put `|i-j|` as the entries at location (i,j), each of which occurs with probability 1/n<sup>2</sup>. You get n zeros down the main diagonal, n-1 ones to either side of the main diagonal for a total of `2(n-1)` ones, `2(n-2)` twos two away from the diag, etc. Eliminate the absolute value => one side of the diagonal is positive, the other is negative, and the probabilities diminish linearly with the difference => triangle.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to know: for all the couples `(a, b)`, computer their distance. Knowing that all the couples `(a, b)` have the same probability of appearance, you will just need to do the average of those distances in order to answer your question.